# 'do_replace()' not working?

Tags: atk4, agiletoolkit

while trying ATK4 I've found a problem:

```
$this->api->db->dsql()->table('person')->set('id', 1)->set('name', 'Test user')->do_replace();
```

This is not working. Then I looked a little bit deeper in ATK4 source and found in */opt/ipism/www/atk4/lib/DB/dsql.php* the lines

```
public $sql_templates=array(
    'select'=>"select [options] [field] [from] [table] [join] [where] [group] [having] [order] [limit]",
    'insert'=>"insert [options_insert] into [table_noalias] ([set_fields]) values ([set_values])",
    'replace'=>"replace [options_replace] into [table_noalias] ([set_fields]) values ([set_values])",
    'update'=>"update [table_noalias] set [set] [where]",
    'delete'=>"delete from  [table_noalias] [where]",
    'truncate'=>'truncate table [table_noalias]',
    'describe'=>'desc [table_noalias]',
);
```

After changing the 'replace'-line into

```
    'replace'=>"replace into [table_noalias] ([set_fields]) values ([set_values])",
```

it worked for me (removing the **options_replace** and appending a '**s**' to **set_value**). I'm using latest version from git with a MySQL database connection.

But I'm not sure, if I'm using 'do-replace()' in the wrong way?

ByE...

By the way: Is there a way to send fixes, without creating an account on GitHub or somewhere?

**Edit:** Here is the output if the **options_replace** isn't removed from the template:

replace [options_replace] into `person` (`id`,`name`) values ("1","John Doe") [:a_2, :a]

### Application Error: Database Query Failed

Exception_DB, code: 0

Additional information:

- pdo_error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[options_replace] into `person` (`id`,`name`) values ('1' at line 1
- mode: replace
- params:

  - :a: 1
  - :a_2: John Doe
- query: replace [options_replace] into `person` (`id`,`name`) values (:a,:a_2)
- template: replace [options_replace] into [table_noalias] ([set_fields]) values ([set_values])

/opt/ipism/www/atk4/lib/DB/dsql.php:1519

**Stack trace:**
File Object NameStack Trace/opt/ipism/www/atk4/lib/**BaseException.php**:63 Exception_DBException_DB->**collectBasicData**(Null)
/opt/ipism/www/atk4/lib/**AbstractObject.php**:545 Exception_DBException_DB->**__construct**("Database Query Failed", Null)
/opt/ipism/www/atk4/lib/DB/**dsql.php**:1519 sample_project_db_db_dsql_mysqlDB_dsql_mysql->**exception**("Database Query Failed")
/opt/ipism/www/atk4/lib/DB/**dsql.php**:1586 sample_project_db_db_dsql_mysqlDB_dsql_mysql->**execute**()
/opt/ipism/www/atk4/lib/DB/**dsql.php**:1624 sample_project_db_db_dsql_mysqlDB_dsql_mysql->**replace**()
/opt/ipism/www/page/**test.php**:40 sample_project_db_db_dsql_mysqlDB_dsql_mysql->**do_replace**()
/opt/ipism/www/atk4/lib/**AbstractObject.php**:306 sample_project_testpage_test->**init**()
/opt/ipism/www/atk4/lib/**ApiFrontend.php**:130 sample_projectFrontend->**add**("page_test", "test", "Content")
/opt/ipism/www/atk4/lib/**ApiWeb.php**:428 sample_projectFrontend->**layout_Content**()
/opt/ipism/www/atk4/lib/**ApiFrontend.php**:39 sample_projectFrontend->**addLayout**("Content")
/opt/ipism/www/atk4/lib/**ApiWeb.php**:275 sample_projectFrontend->**initLayout**()
/opt/ipism/www/**index.php**:15 sample_projectFrontend->**main**()

Note: To hide this information from your users, add $config['logger']['web_output']=false to your config.php file. Refer to documentation on 'Logger' for alternative logging options

Comment: Looks like Romans just fixed this https://github.com/atk4/atk4/commit/24b20865b9e3345a8e7504dfb68b7ef96335009e :)

Comment: It doesn't work as long as **[options_replace]** is contained in the template. Maybe it's because **[options_replace]** is not defined or handled (like **[options_insert]** for example).

Answer (score 0):

Replace is similar to "insert" by it's nature, but instead of failing when primary key is duplicated, it replaces the value.

1. Please add ->debug() to your line before do_replace and give me the output, which would help me understand why that parameter needs removing.
2. set_value seems to be a typo, I have changed and committed it into master: https://github.com/atk4/atk4/commit/24b20865b9e3345a8e7504dfb68b7ef96335009e
3. the best way to submit changes is by creating a pull request. The best way to report issues is through "issues" in github currently.

Comment: to 1: I've inserted the error output at bottom of my question. If I remove the **replace_options** from the template it works. I think, either it should be handled (like **options_insert**) or it should removed from the template.